# Processing: Start a serial communication "master"

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

In processing, seems like you can only connect to an existing serial port`Serial myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);` if the port is not established, you get an error. Is it possible to establish a serial "master "for other devices/programs to connect to? i.e. you can do it in Arduino by `Serial.begin(9600)`

Comment: If you open a serial connection from one application to your Arduino, then no other connection will be possible until you close the port(for example if you open a serial connection from Processing, Serial Monitor won't be able to connect, or if you have Serial Monitor running, Processing won't be able to connect). What do you mean by a "master" connection ?

Comment: I mean if it's possible to simulate something like an Arduino, which allows other serial sessions to connect to. With the Processing's Serial library, you can only connect to existing serial devices. If you run the line `new Serial();` without a existing serial port, you get an error.

Comment: So essentially youre question about a serial port emulator so you can prototype without an arduino, correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea